# Performing initialization of templated class using other templated classes in variadic arguments of constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I wanted to create a *simple* HTML dom builder in C++ and decided I would use a templated `tag<>` class to describe the type of tag this was.

I already used other methods to create the DOM in C++ with some success, but the design wouldn't handle raw strings, so the move to a templated class may assist me in handling that using template specialization (`tag<plain>`).

The issue now is nesting the tags within their constructors using a variadic template. I've been able to implement it with `node`, which holds the root level tags, but any tag-within-tag nesting is a no-go.

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

namespace web {
enum class attrs { charset, name, content, http_equiv, rel, href, id, src, lang };

using attribute = std::pair<attrs, std::string>;

using attribute_type = std::map<attrs, std::string>;

const auto none = attribute_type{};

enum tag_name { html, head, meta, title, link, body, div, script, plain, p, h1, span };

template <typename... Tags> struct node {
    int increment;
    std::tuple<Tags...> tags;

    explicit node(const int incr, Tags... tggs)
        : increment{incr}, tags{std::make_tuple(tggs...)} {}
};

template <tag_name T, typename... Tags> struct tag {
    attribute_type attributes;
    std::tuple<Tags...> tags;

    explicit tag(attribute_type atts, Tags... tggs)
        : attributes{atts.begin(), atts.end()}, tags{std::make_tuple(tggs...)} {
    }
};

template <> struct tag<plain> {
    std::string content;

    explicit tag(std::string val) : content{std::move(val)} {}
};
} // namespace web

int main() {
    using namespace web;
    node page1{2};
    node page2{2, tag<html>{none}};
    node page3{2, tag<html>{{{attrs::lang, "en"}}}};
    node page4{2, tag<meta>{{{attrs::name, "viewport"},
                                  {attrs::content,
                                   "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}}}};
    node page5{2, tag<head>{none}, tag<body>{none}, tag<plain>{"Hello World"}}; // Yet this line still compiles and works as expected...
    node page6{1, tag<span>{none, tag<h1>{none}}}; // error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'tag<html>'
}
```

I want to know how I'm able to aggregate tags inside the node class yet cannot do so inside the `tag` class and, if possible, I would be able to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you really want to compute-time view of html? As you won't be able to read file content (which is "runtime").

Comment: `node page6{1, tag<span, tag<h1>>{none, tag<h1>{none}}};` ? [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32c754a6b86fcf01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that deduction guides, introduced in C++17, work only deducing **all** template arguments.

So calling

```
node page2{2, tag<html>{none}};
```

works because

(1) `tag<html>{none}` doesn't needs template deduction because the first template parameter is explicated where the variadic list (`Tags...`) is empty (no arguments after `none`) so the `tag` is a `tag<html>` and

(2) automatic deduction guides for `node` deduce **all** template arguments (`Tags...`) so `page2` is deduced as `node<tag<html>>`.

The problem arises when you write

```
tag<span>{none, tag<h1>{none}}
```

because, for the `tag<span>`, there is an argument after `none` so the variadic list `Tags...` isn't empty but can't be (automatically, through implicit deduction guides) because you have explicated the first template argument (`span`).

You can obviously solve the problem adding a `make_tag()` function, as suggested by Cruz Jean, but I propose you a different solution that uses automatic deduction guides.

First of all, define a wrapper class `w` for `tag_name`s

```
template <tag_name>
struct w
 { };
```

then rewrite your `tag` class with **two** constructor; the first one for the case with empty internal `tags`

```
  explicit tag (attribute_type atts)
     : attributes{std::move(atts)}
   { }
```

the second one for the general case (also not empty internal `tags` list) that receive a `w<T>` element that permits the automatic deduction also for `T`

```
  explicit tag (w<T>, attribute_type atts, Tags... tggs)
     : attributes{std::move(atts)}, tags{tggs...}
  { }
```

The first constructor permit to maintain the format

```
 tag<html>{none}
```

in case of absence of contained tags; the second one permit this type of `tag` object declarations

```
 tag{w<html>{}, none}

 tag{w<span>{}, none, tag<h1>{none}}
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

namespace web
 {
   enum class attrs
    { charset, name, content, http_equiv, rel, href, id, src, lang };

   using attribute = std::pair<attrs, std::string>;

   using attribute_type = std::map<attrs, std::string>;

   const auto none = attribute_type{};

   enum tag_name
    { html, head, meta, title, link, body, div, script, plain, p, h1, span };

   template <typename... Tags>
   struct node
    {
      int increment;
      std::tuple<Tags...> tags;

      explicit node (int const incr, Tags ... tggs)
         : increment{incr}, tags{tggs...}
       { }
    };

   template <tag_name>
   struct w
    { };

   template <tag_name T, typename ... Tags>
   struct tag
    {
      attribute_type attributes;
      std::tuple<Tags...> tags;

      explicit tag (attribute_type atts)
         : attributes{std::move(atts)}
       { }

      explicit tag (w<T>, attribute_type atts, Tags... tggs)
         : attributes{std::move(atts)}, tags{tggs...}
      { }
    };

   template <>
   struct tag<plain>
    {
      std::string content;

      explicit tag (std::string val) : content{std::move(val)}
       { }
    };
 } // namespace web


int main ()
 {
   using namespace web;
   node page1{2};
   node page2{2, tag<html>{none}};
   node page3{2, tag<html>{{{attrs::lang, "en"}}}};
   node page4{2, tag<html>{{{attrs::name, "viewport"},
       {attrs::content, "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}}}};
   node page5{2, tag<head>{none}, tag<body>{none},
       tag<plain>{"Hello World"}};
   node page6{1, tag{w<span>{}, none, tag<h1>{none}}};
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue of template class type deduction. There's an ambiguity that can be cleared up by a simple function wrapper (or by C++17 deduction guides).

Anyhow, here you go (this works in gcc 8.3 in C++17 mode):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

namespace web
{
    enum class attrs { charset, name, content, http_equiv, rel, href, id, src, lang };

    using attribute = std::pair<attrs, std::string>;

    using attribute_type = std::map<attrs, std::string>;

    const auto none = attribute_type{};

    enum tag_name { html, head, meta, title, link, body, div, script, plain, p, h1, span };

    template <typename... Tags>
    struct node
    {
        int increment;
        std::tuple<Tags...> tags;

        explicit node(const int incr, Tags... tggs) : increment{incr}, tags{tggs...} {}
    };

    template <tag_name T, typename... Tags>
    struct tag
    {
        attribute_type attributes;
        std::tuple<Tags...> tags;

        explicit tag(const attribute_type &atts, Tags... tggs) : attributes(atts), tags(tggs...) {}
    };

    template <>
    struct tag<plain>
    {
        std::string content;

        explicit tag(std::string val) : content(std::move(val)) {}
    };

    template<typename ...Args>
    auto make_node(int incr, Args &&...args)
    {
        return node<std::decay_t<Args>...> ( incr, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    }
    template<tag_name T, typename ...Args>
    auto make_tag(const attribute_type &atts, Args &&...args)
    {
        return tag<T, std::decay_t<Args>...> ( atts, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    }
} // namespace web



int main() {
    using namespace web;
    node page1{2};
    node page2{2, tag<html>{none}};
    node page3{2, tag<html>{{{attrs::lang, "en"}}}};
    node page4{2, tag<meta>{{{attrs::name, "viewport"},
                                  {attrs::content,
                                   "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}}}};
    node page5{2, tag<head>{none}, tag<body>{none}, tag<plain>{"Hello World"}};
    auto page6 = make_node(1, make_tag<span>(none, make_tag<h1>(none))); // works now - uses our make functions
}
```